# peewee on such table

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, peewee

when I was useing peewee ORM, I created a postgresql database, and I made 3 script to createTable and addUser and dropTable, and it work well, but when I try to query the data in Table user, it appear:  on such table : user
there are some of my code:
confiuration.py

```
class Configuration(object):
    DATABASE = 'postgresql://lc:********@localhost:5432/wolfsly'

    @staticmethod
    def init_app(app):
        pass
```

app.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask
from .extensions import db, lm
from .configuration import config

_all_ = ['create_app']

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    config_blueprint(app)
    configure_template_filters(app)
    config_extensions(app)

    return app

def config_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)
```

extensions.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from playhouse.flask_utils import FlaskDB
from flask_login import LoginManager

lm = LoginManager()
db = FlaskDB()
```

and one of my database script
createTable.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from application import create_app
from application.extensions import db


def createTables():
    app = create_app('default')
    from application.models import (User, Project, Photo)
    database = db.database
    database.connect()
    database.create_tables([User, Project, Photo])
    database.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    createTables()
```

when I run my createTable.py it work well and in my database appear 3 tables, and after addUser there is normal data in my User table. But when I try to get user in User table or query data in User Table it respone me "on such table: user"and in my work dir will appear a peewee.db
here is some code in my auth/views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_login import  current_user, login_user
from ..models import User
from . import bpAuth

@bpAuth.route('/login')
def login():
    pass

@bpAuth.route('/test')
def test():
    query = User.select(User.id, User.chinesename)
    print 'test'
    names = [user.chinesename for user in query]
    for user in query:
        print user.chinesename
    u = User.get(User.username == 'lc')
    print u.chinesename
    return u.chinesename
```

and here is some screenshot

```
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWLYo.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldBRV.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Tb7.jpg
```

and it seems when I run my webapp I can't connect my local database.

Comment: put full error message instead of image. Full message - not only `"on such table: user"` - because there can be other usefull imformation - ie. which line makes problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be helpful if you shared your model definitions or the full traceback. Honestly you went through so much effort but you forgot to include the **actually useful** information.

For one, try in your User model to rename it to "users":

```
class User(db.Model):
    username = CharField()
    # etc, other fields
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
```